# how to determine outliers in sample affected by ascertainment bias

Tags: mathematical-statistics, outliers, algorithms

I don't know if this is a really silly question as I'm in no way a statistician and I don't know if this is something that's actually quite rudimentary... Thanks for reading in advance too it got kind of wordy too since I don't have a sample data set.

Essentially I have data that is plotted as a linear series that represents random sampling (**I'm essentially trying to determine true outliers from what would be an incorrect call based on ascertainment bias**). I'm plotting along an x-axis, where as x increases, my sample size increases (it's not actually a time-series, but is similar). Each of the data are sampled randomly (think percent heads vs # coin tosses plotted along a time series). I'm basically trying to pull out and record events that appear as an outlier to the trend.

I am aware of interquartile ranges and moving averages. I can't use calculations involving interquartile range as some data are more heavily affected by ascertainment bias than others (esp at low sample size). THIS IS KEY: **the goal is not for the algorithm to tell me that outliers occur at low sample sizes [as this is obvious], but I want it to specifically call outliers taking ascertainment bias into consideration (ie. a coin tossed twice, both times producing heads is NOT an outlier, even though heads is at 100% and expected average is 50%, yet a coin tossed 10000x and heads is at 80% would potentially be an outlier**). Note I only have one entry per sample size (so I definitely can't do IQR within a single sample size). I can't change this, my coin is flipped 10x only once before I move on to 11x and then 12x etc.

I don't see the point in using moving average since, I already know what the presumed intended average is supposed to be (in a coin toss example, I know the average is to approach 50% as sample size increases).

Is there a simple algorithm one could use for this? I don't have an actual example dataset yet, but essentially I'm sampling data completely randomly. The easiest applicable example is the coin toss example I have been using. If you can cater an answer to that I can just work on integrating that into my dataset after.

Edit: To clarify, I'm tossing a different coin for each data point along the x axis (ie. all of the 10x tosses are with one coin, 11x a different coin, 12x a yet different coin, etc.). The point is to identify coins that are NOT at 50:50 heads vs tails. I know the immediate reaction is to wonder why I don't toss them all the same # of times, but this is something out of my control, that's the current situation I am working with. Also, I'm asking about the "best" method to pull out as many true outliers as statistically possible, I know I can't determine all of them (the coin tossed only once is clearly impossible to determine whether it is a 50:50 coin or not).

Comment: (i) "ascertainment bias" was a new one on me. Wikipedia's [Sampling bias page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias) seems to regard it as essentially synonymous with sampling bias. (ii) the notion of a 'true outlier' is somewhat tricky -- whether or not an observation is an outlier very much depends on your model; an observation that's perfectly consistent with one model would be a bizarre peculiarity in relation to another. So an observation might be outlying with reference to some given/assumed model, but it's always conditional on that assumption.

Comment: (iii) Given that model-dependence, and the possibility that the assumptions of a coin-model might fail as a model for whatever you're really doing, you may need to carefully consider whether an outlier is an indication of a problem with the model rather than whatever the coin represents.

Comment: If the coins for each entry are independent then (a) why would this introduce any bias into the proportion of heads tossed, and (b) have you considered a simple hypothesis test for binomial proportion with adjustment for multiple testing, e.g., Bonferroni correction?